# move screen over image in titanium javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I need to create an effect like this in this site withe the name:

[Link from the example site](https://codepen.io/drygiel/pen/KbhmA)

```
//I need this in javascript
```

The problem is that the created effect is an image with all designs. How can I move trough the entire image and show only part of the image in javascript for android and IOS?
[image: Image of all situations of the name]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved it using

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <Label id="label" top="80" onClick="doClick">Play Sign</Label>
    <View height="84">
        <ImageView width="255" height="7224" id="sigimage" top="0" image="/testImages/0D8Zt.png"></ImageView>
    </View>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

**index.tss**

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
}
"Label": {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    color: "#000"
}

"#label": {
    font: {
        fontSize: 18
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
var interval = null;
var i=0;

function doClick(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    i = 0;
    replay();
}
replay();
function replay(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(i<86){
            $.sigimage.top = -i*84;
            i++;
            Ti.API.info('i = '+i);
        }else{
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    },10);
}

$.index.open();
```

a little trick, hope this will help you. :)

[image]

Comment: I have edited a little the code but solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a list of images it is very simple. First, make an imageView in Alloy

```
<ImageView id="signature" />
```

Next add all the images in tss and set the speed of a single image in ms

```
"#signature": {
    images: ['image1.png','image2.png','image3.png',....],
    duration: 50,
    repeatCount: 1
}
```

In my example I set it at 50ms. Meaning you have 20 images per second. I also set `repeatCount` to 1 so it doesn't repeat (`0` is default & endless)

Then, as soon as you want the signature to "start" call `start()` in the `js` controller file:

```
$.signature.start();
```

Read the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-method-start) about it.

Comment: but I think its only a single image.